# Integral involving exponential of inverse fourth power of sine

Tags: definite-integrals

I need to solve the following integral:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^2(\theta) e^{-\frac{c}{\sin^4 \theta}} d\theta
\end{align*}
I tried a few changes of variables to make it look like a Gaussian integral, as well as integration by parts, but could not get it to a manageable form, mainly because the $sin^4$ term is in the denominator of the exponent. I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: There are a lot of integrals without closed form, what makes you think that it has a closed form?

Comment: Nothing in particular. If an exact closed form is not feasible, a close upper bound would be useful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use symmetry to write this as twice the integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$, then substitute $t = \sin(\theta)^{-1/4}$ to make it
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-ct^2}\; dt}{t^2 \sqrt{t-1}}$$
But I don't think there's a closed form for this, unless you allow hypergeometric functions: Maple gives
$$ {\frac {24\,{c}^{5/4}{\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}(\frac34,\frac54;\,\frac32,\frac94;\,-c)}
 \left( \Gamma \left( 3/4 \right)  \right) ^{2}-20\,\sqrt {2}\pi\,
{\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}(\frac14,\frac34;\,\frac12,\frac74;\,-c)}{c}^{3/4}+15\,\pi\,\Gamma
 \left( 3/4 \right) }{30 \;\Gamma \left( 3/4 \right) }}
$$

This corresponds to the series
$$4\,{c}^{5/4}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {\Gamma \left( 3/4+
k \right) }{ \left( 5+4\,k \right)(1+2k)! } \left(-4c \right) ^{k}}-2\,c^{3/4}\,\sum _{k
=0}^{\infty }{\frac {\Gamma \left( 1/4+k \right)  \left( -4\,c
 \right) ^{k}}{ \left( 3+4\,k \right)(2k)! }}+\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

so for $c$ not too big, partial sums of this will give good approximations.

On the other hand, for large $c$ you can get good approximations using Watson's lemma.